# How to connect an external Django backend with IBM Watson (Notebook)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I'm doing a small project that I don't know how-to connect IBM Watson with Django backend and even looking for the docs: I can't find examples, documentation or tutorials.

Basically, I want to create Jobs (Notebooks running) remotely, but I need to send an ID to each notebook because when I run a notebook I need to specify which file are going to process from Cloud Storage ("MY-PROJECT-COS"). The situation shown in the Figure below describes that.
[image]

The pipeline that I want to implement is like the Figure below. And this problem just stopped the whole project. I will really appreciate any suggestion, recommendations and solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [Watson Data APIs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/watson-data-api-cpd). Especially, [Create a job](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/watson-data-api-cpd#jobs-create) and [Start a run for a job](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/watson-data-api-cpd#job-runs-create)  API calls. Use the request body to pass the specific `ID`.

> You can use a collection of Watson Data REST APIs associated with
> Watson Studio and Watson Knowledge Catalog to manage data-related
> assets and connections in analytics projects and catalogs on IBM Cloud
> Pak for Data.
>
> Catalog data Use the catalog and asset APIs to create catalogs to
> administer your assets, associate properties with those assets, and
> organize the users who use the assets. Assets can be notebooks or
> connections to files, database sources, or data assets from a
> connection.
>
> Govern data Use the governance and workflows APIs to implement data
> policies and a business glossary that fits to your organization to
> control user access rights to assets and to uncover data quality and
> data lineage.
>
> Add and find data Use the discovery, search, and connections APIs to
> add and find data within your projects and catalogs.

You can also access a local version of this API docs on each Cloud Pak
for Data installation:
`https://{cpd_cluster_host}/data-api/api-explorer`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to use Pak For Data but appears the message "License required: You don't have any licenses. You can acquire one through Passport Advantage Online." Is there any other way to do the connection? I heard about something called Functions but can it handle a WatsonJob creation?